# In Magento2.3.2 :Mail send settings :- Is it work through localhost or Not?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email, transactional-mail, magento2.3.2

In Magento2.3.2 :Mail send settings :-what are the possible ways for mail-send(like need for order,shipping,delivery).

I check store->configuration->Advance->system->mail sending settings...

I need to know about That configuration like Host :'localhost' Port:'25'

Is it work through localhost or Not?

Any other solution for mail sending In magento2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup a mail server on your localhost unless you can use modules SMTP to sendmail.

Comment: I use ubuntu18.04.2-LTS How to setup mail server in localhost , Or which SMTP modules is best for send mail in magento2.3.

Comment: I used magepal SMTP extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use magepal free extension for email sending , using gmail you can easily configure this

[mageplaza extension link](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/configure-gmail-smtp-magento-2.html)